# Timed Metadata for HTTP Live Streaming in android

Tags: android, ios4, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

Is there any ways or methods to read timed metadata which is present in MPEG-2 Transport Streams (.ts files) for Android.

However, This feature is available in Apple iOS.

Regards,
S

Comment: +1. Really interested to hear if this problem ever got solved.